# Problem in Processing .aif file in Matlab

Tags: matlab, audio

I am trying to use the following crossfading code in MATLAB. I use `audioread()` to open the audio signals and I convert both of them to mono. When I use .wav files, it works perfectly fine. But when I use .aif files, I get the following warning message for the last line:

`"Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or logicals."`

Is there any way I can fix it without having to convert my audio signals?

```
n = 200;

W = linspace(1,0,n)';                                    

S1(end-n+1:end) = S1(end-n+1:end).*W;

S2(1:n) = S2(1:n).*(1-W);

S12 = zeros(size(S1,1) + size(S2,1) - n, 1);

S12(1:size(S1,1)) = S1;

S12(end-size(S2,1)+1:end) = S12(end-size(S2,1)+1:end) + S2; %this is where I get the warning
```

Comment: a programming/debugging question, not a signal processing question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to access to the index number:

`end-size(S2,1)+1`

That can be negative or zero, and that's why you may be getting that error message. You have to be sure that the length of `S2` is such that the final result is positive.